# Computing determinant $a_{ij = 1}, a_{ii} = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

So the question is in the title (the determinat of a matrix $(a_{ij})$ and diagonal elements are zeros) such that all the off-diagonal elements are $1$. I have no idea how to approach this. I am looking for a hints. Solutions are also good but hints would be better.

Comment: Have you tried computing a few examples?

Comment: @ Noah Solomon yes, 2, 3, 4. Haven't seen any connection whatsoever.

Comment: the eigenvalues for the square matrix with all entries $1$  are easy to work out. Then subtracting off the identity matrix shifts each eigenvalue down by $1$

Comment: now that I think about it, we often get questions on $u v^T,$  where $u,v$ are column vectors. In this case, both $u=v$ are vectors of all $1$

Comment: ^Yep, there are a lot of questions on this site which are basically rank-$1$ updates to a diagonal matrix.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Note that $A+I$ is a matrix of all ones, which clearly has rank-$1$. Hence, $0$ is an eigenvalue of $A+I$ with multiplicity $n-1$, and $?$ is the last eigenvalue with multiplicity $1$. It's not hard to work out what this last eigenvalue is if you think about what happens when you multiply $A+I$ by a vector of all ones.

Then, you can get the eigenvalues of $A$ by simply subtracting $1$ from each eigenvalue of $A+I$. Finally, the determinant of $A$ is the product of the eigenvalues of $A$.

EDIT: This is basically what Will Jagy suggested in the comments a minute earlier.